# Cannot get Perforce Triggers to work properly

Tags: python, triggers, perforce

Been trying to get this working all day, and i just can't figure out why its not working. 
Trying to implement a simple trigger to run when the user submitted a file.

example in the .tmp file:

hello_trigger change-submit //testDepot/... "python F:/triggers/hello_trigger.py"

when i try to submit a file i get this:

Submit validation failed -- fix problems then use 'p4 submit -c 10199'.
'hello_trigger' validation failed: python: can't open file 'F:/triggers/hello_trigger.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

File exists and can be read, so its not a python issue.. same error with a .txt or .bat file.

From what i can gather the problem seems to be coming from the depot line in the trigger.

//testDepot/... fails

//depot/... doesnt fail, but the script is never fired off.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

also testDepot is a stream not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

```
python: can't open file 'F:/triggers/hello_trigger.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

seems pretty clear that the file doesn't exist, at least from the point of view of this trigger command.  Some things to double check:

1. This is running on the **server machine**, i.e. the place where the p4d service is running.  If you have the script on your client machine the Python executable on the server isn't going to be able to find it!
2. Similarly, this is being run by whatever user is running p4d (on Windows this is usually the SYSTEM user, which may have limited permissions).  Does that user have permission to read this path?
3. Could it be that your version of Python on Windows doesn't know how to handle paths with Unix-style forward slashes?  (Many tools will normalize these for you but you shouldn't depend on it!)  Try using a valid Windows path, i.e. `F:\triggers\hello_trigger.py`.